# Initial value problem $x'=x^{2/3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just analyzing the IVP $x'=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ with initial condition $x(0)=0$. It is obvious that there is a solution which is not unique, since it is not Lipschitz (not bounded near 0). My book says it has a solution that satifies $x(t)=0$ iff $t\in [t_1,t_2]$ for eached fixed $t_1<0<t_2$.

When I divide both sides by $x^{2/3}$ tae integrals etc. I get $x(t)=(\frac{t}{3})^3$. I do not see the the above equivalance.

Comment: There seem  to be $\geq1$ typos in your question.

Comment: it has a solution that satifies $x(t)=0$ iff $t\in [t_1,t_2]$ for eached fixed $t_1<0<t_2$ - can you please put some quantifiers on this? I can't understand at all what you're asking.

Comment: How does this specific solution looks like? I want to show that the IVP has a solution that satifies $x(t)=0$ iff $t\in[t_1,t_2]$ for eached fix $t_1<0<t_2$, but I do not know how

Comment: Ok, you have a if and only statement. On the left of $\iff$ you have $x(t)=0$. You need to quantify this. Is it $\forall t(x(t)=0)$? Maybe $\exists t(x(t)=0$? And where does $t$ range?

Comment: Well I guess it should mean $\exists t(x(t)=0)$. If it would be for all $t$ than the solution would be simply 0. It might be possible to conclude from the fact that there is such a $t$ that this $t$ must be an element of an interval $[t_1,t_2]$

Comment: The solution would be $0$ only locally (depending on where $t$ ranges). So you want to prove that $$\exists t(x(t)=0)\iff \exists t, t_1, t_2(t\in [t_1, t_2]\land t_1<0<t_2)?$$

Comment: Yes exactly,this makes sense.

Comment: @Alkibiades Well, in the above equivalence the RHS is obviously true at all times and the LHS is true if you take the null function everywhere, so I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: Juding by Jonas' answer what you're asked to prove is this: $$\forall t_1,t_2\in \Bbb R\color{blue}(t_1<0<t_2\implies\\ (\text{there exists a solution } x \text{ to the IVP such that} (\forall t\in \Bbb R)(x(t)=0\iff t\in [t_1, t_2]))\color{blue})$$

Comment: Being zero on $(-\infty,t_0]$ exactly is allright. Being zero on $(-\infty,t_1]\cup[t_2,+\infty)$ for some $t_1\lt t_2$ is problematic since it seems to require to be able to define a function $x\mapsto x^{2/3}$ on $x\lt0$ (a move one may find good reasons not to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(t) =
  \begin{cases}
   \left(\frac{t-t_1}{3}\right)^3 & \text{if } t<t_1 \\
   0       & \text{if } t_1\leq t\leq t_2 \\
   \left(\frac{t-t_2}{3}\right)^3 & \text{if } t>t_2
  \end{cases}$$

works.

You divide by $x^{2/3}$, but you cannot divide by $0$, so the validity of that division only holds when you know $x\neq 0$.  The above shows all possible solutions; $x$ can only be zero on an interval, because once positive it stays positive to the right, and once negative it stays negative to the left.  The initial condition just tells you that $t_1\leq 0\leq t_2$.  ($t_1$ could be $-\infty$ and $t_2$ could be $+\infty$.)

Comment: What is $x^{2/3}$ when $x\lt0$?

Comment: @Did: It is either the real cube root of the square of $x$, or the square of the real cube root of $x$, which are equal.

Comment: Right, I understand this unorthodox convention is needed to make the exercise true.