# ODE with infinitely many solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, arithmetic-dynamics

We have that: $ \dot{x}=x^{2/3} $, and $x(0)=0$. This Initial Value Problem has infinitely many solutions (is a problem in my Dynamics Book, so I'm sure about that), but personally I could found only two, $x=t^3/27$ and $x=0$. Normally I would say that a linear combination of the solutions will also be a solution, but in that case we have $x=0$. How can I find another?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524676/initial-value-problem-x-x2-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is translation invariant. That means that if $x=f(t)$ is a solution, then $x=f(t-c)$ is also a solution. The way to get infinitely many solutions is by pasting $x=0$ with $x=(t-c)^3/27$ at $x=c>0$. It easy so see that the resulting function is regular and satisfies the equation at all points.

You should get the family of solutions given in MPW's answer in this way (the constant $c_1$ there is related to my $c$ above).

Comment: But I need to have x(0)=0, which only happens if c=0

Comment: Can you please clarify what does 'pasting' mean here?

Comment: @NatashaJ It means your solution is equal to zero up to $x=c$ and equal to $(t-c)^3/27$ for $x\ge c$. The resulting function has a continuous derivative and is thus a classical solution on all the real line.

Comment: Ok thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Try Wolfram Alpha. It shows the solution as
$$y(x) = \frac{1}{27}\left(3c_1x^2 + 3c_1^2x + c_1^3 + x^3\right)$$
where each value of $c_1$ yields a different solution.